# how to create multi file with touch and using spaces?

Tags: bash

I want to create multiple file creation with touch, but I am constrained by space, because I want to use space in my files like this

```
1 Joe Arnold 
2 lucky man 
3 directory lib
```

I try like this

```
touch 1 joe arnold
```

after I execute it, the command has 3 files (1, joe, arnold)

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quote (`"`), enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes.

```
$ touch "1 Joe Arnold"
$ ls
'1 Joe Arnold'
```

You may want to read [bash manual regarding double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html).